# What's highest speed at which I could possibly travel?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm trying to determine (preferably in %, where 100% is the standard speed for the Pyro, Spy, Engineer, and Sniper) the highest possible speed at which I could travel in TF2 (on a VAC-secure server, so without cheats).

So far, I've got: A Demoman charging (250%) with 4 heads on the Eyelander (+30%), whilst being whipped with the Disciplinary Action (+37.5%) having just won a round (say, of KOTH) (+10%), totaling 327.5%. Also, a Medic, with the Quick Fix, healing this person, would match this speed. Is this the highest possible theoretical speed for any given TF2 class in any situation?

---

Edit: to avoid stupidly-high speeds (and because it's not very useful), I'm only considering running speed (so sticky jumping, rocket jumping, any kind of jumping doesn't count).

Comment: Does "any situation" include being blasted through the air by a pile of stickybombs?

Comment: Then I'm going to go with a demoman placing 14 stickies in one spot with the Scottish Resistance then being ubercharged so he can sticky jump. I got from one end of mvm_bigrock to the other before my ubercanteen ran out.

Comment: @Studoku Is there a limiting number of stickies (beyond which, your jump height/speed won't increase)? And what speed does a sticky jump with 14 stickies correspond to?

Comment: @Studoku Also, assuming that increasing the number of stickies increases speed (without limit), what about MvM, sticky jumping using the Sticky jumper with 14*2.5=35 stickies?

Comment: You can't increase the number of stickies that can be placed at once. You could use a team of 30 enemy demomen I suppose but you'd need them all to detonate at once.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any info on the exact mechanics of detonating 434 stickybombs underneath someone.

Comment: I think the scenario that you gave in the question is the highest.

Comment: The medic with a QF will only match the base speed of a class + base speed improvements. For example, you can heal a BFB scout and run at his speed, but if he uses Crit-A-Cola, you'll slowly get further away from him (assuming you run in a straight line)

Comment: Does it need to be the whole body, will just a body part do? If the latter, a scout taking a rocket crit to the back while running probably *partially* takes the top spot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Running

Normal running speed is capped at 520 Hammer units per second (a Hammer unit is 1/16 of a foot).  It became this when the Scout's Baby Face Blaster was released, up from its former limit of 400 (I think) Hammer units per second.  This is a **hard** cap and only one ability will let you go over that speed...

Side Note: "Normal" 100% running speed is 300 Hammer Units per second.

### DemoMan Charging

The charge speed is exempt from the normal speed limit and instead maxes out at 750 Hammer units per second.  It will go slower than that if the Demo is using a Skullcutter), but never faster. The length of the charge is normally 1 second, but the Claidheamh Mòr will increase this to 1.5 seconds.

The shield will have a 12 second recharge time, 6 second if using the Persian Persuader.

So... here's a quick chart of the speesd after 1, 2, 7, and 8 seconds.  8 being chosen because it's after the second Persian Persuader charge.

[image: Scout vs. Demo speeds]

As you can see, a stock Scout will *barely* outrun the fastest demo over time, but a Baby Face Blaster Scout can outrun everything else.

However, the fastest movement speed in the game?  Taking a short range critical Direct Hit rocket while jumping.  It's powerful enough to send you all the way between pl_upward's A and B points in seconds.  Of course, only a Dead Ringer Spy can actually **survive** that since it does 450 damage.

Comment: So, will a charging Demoman with 4 heads on his Eyelander charge at the same speed as a charging Demoman with zero heads? Are you saying that 750 H/s is the absolute maximum "on-ground" speed?

Comment: @alexqwx Yes and yes... but that 750 is also capped as to how long you can do it.

Answer (score 5):

The speed you have posted is the highest speed, not counting explosive-jumping.    Of course, in regards to "standard running speed", a Scout

- with BFB at 100% boost = 173% base moving speed
- under Concheror effect or Disciplinary Whip effect +40% of base (120%)
- Round Won  +10% of base (120%)
- under Crit-A-Cola effect = +25%

would clearly beat out the demo.

Here's a nice infographic that shows running speeds: http://thomaspark.me/project/tf2speeds/

You'll notice that obviously the demo has the fastest burst running speed, but long-term, the scout wins, hands down, every single time.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that the Crit-a-Cola doesn't have an effect on speed boost when the Baby Face's Blaster is at full boost.

Comment: I'm curious if either of these are beat out by the aerial speed of a rocket jump skip or sticky jump.  I imagine one or the other might be able to outdo both a Demo AND a Scout, given how much mobility I've seen soldiers and Demo have.

Comment: @Zibbobz There is no doubt that a rocketjump or a stickyjump will ALWAYS beat out the normal running speed, but alex has specifically requested running speed, excluding the boost you get from explosive jumping.

Answer (score 2):

Trimping (otherwise known as charge jumping or charge ramping) allows you to travel at speeds above 2100 hammer units per second if you strafe in the air,. That's three times faster than a charging Demoman on the ground. This is by far the fastest way you can travel that isn't very situational.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer to show what speed is actually possible in vanilla TF2.

---

If there was no movement speed cap, then it'd be theoretically possible to achieve an infinite amount of speed.
You'd have to make a map infinitely high, and design it for an infinite rocket sync. Using the cow mangler, go to the top, fall off, and start syncing rockets. As the cow mangler does not require ammo, you can sync an infinite amount of rockets. At the bottom, get a medic to ÜberCharge you when you do the sync.

After more digging, I have found the command that limits the velocity at [Valve's Developer Site](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/List_of_TF2_console_commands_and_variables).
It is under "sv_maxvelocity", and by default it is set at 3500hu/s per axis. This should mean that the maximum velocity can be achieved when going at max velocity both vertically and horizontally, hence we find the final maximum at 3500sqrt(2) ≈ 4950hu/s.
You could perhaps test this command on a custom server with cl_showpos 1.